# how to link facebook application page to facebook page

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook into my Android App. When a user now posts a new event to his wall it is signed by my app. Clicking the link of the app directs to [the facebook app landing page](http://apps.facebook.com/bikecomputer/). But I would like to link to the  [actual facebook fan page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/BikeComputer/151749984937990) as I don't want to write a facebook app. Maybe I'm a noob but I did not find any documentation regarding this.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible by removing Canvas URL from application settings and merging Application profile Page with Facebook Page (how to do merge described in [Removing App Profile Pages](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) blog post).

Once your application will not have Canvas URL (currently it does have this defined) users clicking on application link in post will be directed to associated Facebook Page)

Comment: Well, I actually already linked the pages, as you may see on the site page. I now removed the Canvas Url but now nothing is linked anymore...

Comment: This is working perfectly for my app. Links in posts pointing to Application Profile Page (which is merged with Facebook Page), so once clicked user goes to Facebook Page. Have you configured your "App Type" for your application to be Native in Advanced Settings?

Comment: Got it! Deleted the site page and added from the app page settings a "community page" Now it links, thank you :D